Как частично перезаписать или добавить новые без удаления старых значения множественного поля типа файл Битрикс24
в сущности сделки вручную добавила поле типа файл с множественным значение. В бекенде на python отправляю данные по апи в битрикс
делаю так метод crm.deal.update отправляю
{
            "id": ид сделки,
            "fields": {
                название поля:
                [
                    {
                        "fileData": [
                            "название фаила",
                            file_base64,
                        ],
                    },
                {
                        "fileData": [
                            "название фаила",
                            file_base64,
                        ],
                    },
                ]
            },
        },

оба фаила записываются. Но когда я хочу добавить в поле фаил не стирая старые я делаю по документации
{
        "id": "ид сделки",
        "fields": {
            "название поля": [
                {"id": "ид фаила который уже записан"},
                {"id": "ид фаила который уже записан"},
                {
                    "fileData": [
                        "название фаила",
                        "file_base64",
                    ],
                },
            ]
        },
    }

и он всегда стирает старые и записывает новый. Возможно вы подскажите более правильный метод добавление файлов без удаления прошлых. Документация https://apidocs.bitrix24.ru/api-reference/crm/universal/crm-item-update.html#kak-obnovit-polzovatelskoe-pole-tipa-file - не работает как описана

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Возможные ошибки:
    {
        "id": "ид сделки",
        "fields": {
            "название поля": [
                {"id": "ид фаила который уже записан"}, -- вместо целого числа передаётся строка
                {"id": "ид фаила который уже записан"},
                {           -- неверный формат
                    "fileData": [
                        "название фаила",
                        "file_base64",
                    ],
                },
            ]
        },
    }

Должно быть:
    {
        "id": "ид сделки",
        "fields": {
            "название поля": [
                {"id": 10},
                {"id": 20},
                [
                    "название фаила",
                    "file_base64",
                ],
            ]
        },
    }

